# POJO, JPA bindings and checkboxes

Tags: playframework

Play uses "Unresolved parameters are safely ignored. Type mismatches are also safely ignored." when binding parameters to POJOs. It works great most of the time.

But this causes trouble with checkboxes, since unchecked checkboxes are not sent in the parameter list.

The CRUD module has solved this by inserting a hidden input-field right after the checkbox. This works because Play only reads the first of the two identical parameters to bind to.

Source from CRUD module, displaying a checkbox:

```
<input id="object_isInvoiceable" type="checkbox" name="object.isInvoiceable" />
<input type="hidden" name="object.isInvoiceable" value="false" />
```

Another way is by not passing the checkbox as a member of the object but as a separate parameter. It is then possible to catch this in the Controller and set the object.member there, like this:

```
<input id="object_isInvoiceable" type="checkbox" name="isInvoiceableExtraParamFromHell" />
```

and in the controller:

```
public static void save(Event object, Boolean isInvoiceableExtraParamFromHell) {
    if(isInvoiceableExtraParamFromHell == null) {
        object.isInvoiceable = false;
    }
    else {
        object.isInvoiceable = true;
    }

    ... validation etc ...

    object.save();

    ... render etc ...
}
```

I do not like alternative 1 because how can I be sure that the order of the params are sent correctly in all browsers.

I do not like alternative 2 because then I have to manage separate parameters and modify my controller methods if I change the object.

Is there some better way of doing this? I'm quite new to Play Framework, so I might have missed some Annotation or something.

EDIT:

I was a bit unclear earlier. The problem is not when creating a new object, then I can set it to default to FALSE like Codemwnci suggested. The problem is when binding to an already existing JPA object.

From playframework [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers):

> You can automatically bind a JPA object using the HTTP to Java binding.
>
> You can provide the user.id field yourself in the HTTP parameters. When Play finds the id field, it loads the matching instance from the database before editing it. The other parameters provided by the HTTP request are then applied. So you can save it directly.

In this case it will not set the member value to any defaults.

As an example, I already have an JPA object stored in the database, that has isInvoiceable set to TRUE. I render this object to the template. If I now uncheck the checkbox the parameter will not be sent, thus the isInvoiceable will still be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new objects, you can do the following

If you are binding POJOs, then simply defaulting the value within the POJO should be sufficient.

For example

```
public class Event extends Model {

    public Boolean isInvoiceable = Boolean.FALSE;
    ...
    ...
}
```

For existing objects, you can do a slight variation on the theme that CRUD uses, by putting a JQuery onclick action against it, so that the value of the checkbox always sets the hidden value, and it is this hidden value that is mapped to the POJO.

So, for example

```
<input id="object_isInvoiceable_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ignoredformfield" />
<input id="object_isInvoiceable_formfield" type="hidden" name="object.isInvoiceable" value="false" />

<script>$("#object_isInvoiceable_checkbox").click(function(
    $("object_isInvoiceable_formfield").value("$("#object_isInvoiceable_checkbox").is(":checked")");
));</script>
```

Note: I have not checked the javascript code, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work with already stored JPA objects. I was a bit unclear in my post earlier and have edited it.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like reasonable workaround. Another would be to put a selectbox with just Yes/No or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution, which avoids the need for hidden/extra fields in the template.

The view code:

```
<input id="object_isInvoiceable" type="checkbox" name="object.isInvoiceable" />
```

The controller code:

```
public static void save(Event object) {
    if(params.get("object.isInvoiceable") == null) {
        object.isInvoiceable = false;
    }

    ... validation etc ...

    object.save();

    ... render etc ...
}
```

Works well for me.